# SQL Server Stored Procedure in Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to write a function in Postgres for the Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure shown here.
Please help. I want to use this stored procedure in postgres as function.

```
USE [EMS_Demo_Db]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_HourWise]    Script Date: 16-12-2014 10:48:53 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_HourWise]
@date_param datetime 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @start_time datetime = dateadd(HOUR, 6, @date_param)

; WITH Hours AS (
   SELECT dateadd(HOUR, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY From_Time) - 1, @start_time) AS From_Time,
          dateadd(HOUR, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY From_Time), @start_time) AS To_Time
   FROM   Table_2
)
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,@date_param, 103)
 as Date_def, convert(time(0), h.From_Time) AS From_Time, convert(time(0), h.To_Time) AS To_Time,
       MAX(t1.Param_Val) - MIN(t1.Param_Val) as Cal_ParamValue
FROM   Table_1 t1
JOIN   Hours h ON t1.Timestamp_col BETWEEN h.From_Time AND h.To_Time
WHERE  Timestamp_col BETWEEN @start_time AND dateadd(HOUR, 24, @start_time)
GROUP  BY h.From_Time, h.To_Time
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER  BY h.From_Time
END
```

Converted SP but it is giving error as

> Unexpected End of function definition at end of input Line 17 : END$BODY$

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_hourwise(OUT from_time time without time zone, OUT to_time time without time zone, OUT param_value bigint, INOUT timestamp_col timestamp without time zone) RETURNS record AS
$BODY$DECLARE v_start_time timestamp(3) = interval '6 HOUR' + @date_param;
BEGIN
With Hours As (
SELECT v_start_time + (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY from_time) - 1) *  INTERVAL '1 day' AS from_time,
v_start_time + (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY from_time)) *  INTERVAL '1 day' AS to_time
   FROM   table_2
)
SELECT CAST(time(0) h.from_time), CAST(time(0) h.to_time),
       MAX(t1.param_value) - MIN(t1.param_value)
FROM   Table_1 t1
JOIN   Hours h ON t1.timestamp_col BETWEEN h.from_time AND h.to_time
WHERE  timestamp_col BETWEEN v_start_time AND interval '24 HOUR' + v_start_time
GROUP  BY h.from_time, h.to_time
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER  BY h.from_time 
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF;
```

Comment: `convert` translates to `cast()`. The `;` goes at the **end** of a statement not at the beginning. For examples of functions returning results see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html

Comment: What about dateadd,With AS...Can you post the converted SP

Comment: This is not a free code writing service you have to show some efforts of your own. Common table expressions are the same: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html Date arithmetics is also explained in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Let me clarify this - you ask us to do your job, for free, while you still keep the money you collect for doing your job? Start learning your job then you do not have to ask around for other people to do your work.

Comment: Let me clarify this @Tom i m not getting any of the money from this.I am new to these technology so i am asking that rather asking the whole complete job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified and finally resolved issues got the required result.Below is the correct and the tested stored procedure. Thanks everyone for the help.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tested_sp(INOUT date_param date, OUT from_time time without time zone, OUT to_time time without time zone, OUT cal bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE 
     start_time Timestamp  = interval '6 HOUR' + date_param;
  BEGIN
return query
      With Hours As (
        SELECT  INTERVAL '1 hour' * (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY table_2.from_time) - 1 ) + start_time AS from_time,
      INTERVAL '1 hour' * (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY table_2.from_time)) + start_time AS to_time
        FROM   table_2
      )
      SELECT date_param::date as Date_Def,CAST(h.from_time as time) as from_time, 
             CAST(h.to_time as time) as to_time,
             CAST(SUM(t1.param_value) AS bigint) as Cal
      FROM   table_1 t1
        JOIN  Hours h ON t1.timestamp_col BETWEEN h.from_time AND h.to_time
      WHERE  timestamp_col BETWEEN start_time AND interval '24 HOUR' + start_time
      GROUP  BY h.from_time, h.to_time
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ORDER  BY h.from_time;
  END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: Don't add additional information (and questions) as answers. **Edit** your question

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your script:

1. you need to separate the "dollar quote" from the actual keywords. The most common way to do this is to write the "dollar quote" on a line of it's own:

   ```
   $BODY$
   DECLARE 
     ...
   END
   $BODY$
   ```
2. Statements need to be terminated with a `;`

   ```
   order by h.from_time; --<< the ; makes a difference
   ```
3. A block needs to be terminated with a `;` as well:

   ```
   END; --<< the ; makes a difference
   $BODY$
   ```
4. Your select statement has no target, but as you want to simply return the result you can use `return query`
5. Parameters are not prefixed with `@` as clearly documented in the manual: 
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html
6. There is no parameter `date_parm` that you are using for the declaration of `v_start_time`
7. The assignment operator is `:=` not `=`
8. You never assign values to your `OUT` parameters, so you can just declare them as `IN` (or leave out the qualifier completely)
9. The `cast()` functions needs the `as` keyword and the parameters are reversed [as documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-oper.html):

   ```
   CAST(h.from_time AS time(0))
   ```

   you can also use Postgres' shorter `::` notation: `h.from_time::time`
10. For clarity you probably want to define the function as `returns table (...)` and specify the column names in the function declaration. When you use `returns record` you need to specify the column names each time you *use* the function.

To return one of the input parameters in the result, add a column definition to the `returns table (...)` part and include the parameter as part of the select statement:

Taking all of the above something like the following should do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_hourwise(from_time time without time zone, to_time time without time zone, date_param date) 
RETURNS table  (some_date_column date, from_time time, to_time time, diff integer)
AS
$BODY$

  DECLARE 
     v_start_time timestamp(3) := interval '6 HOUR' + date_param;  --- I don't know which parameter you want to use here.

  BEGIN

    return query
      With Hours As (
        SELECT v_start_time + (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY from_time) - 1) *  INTERVAL '1 day' AS from_time,
               v_start_time + (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY from_time)) *  INTERVAL '1 day' AS to_time
        FROM   table_2
      )
      SELECT date_param, 
             CAST(h.from_time as time), 
             CAST(h.to_time as time),
             MAX(t1.param_value) - MIN(t1.param_value) as diff
      FROM   Table_1 t1
        JOIN  Hours h ON t1.timestamp_col BETWEEN h.from_time AND h.to_time
      WHERE  timestamp_col BETWEEN v_start_time AND interval '24 HOUR' + v_start_time
      GROUP  BY h.from_time, h.to_time
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ORDER  BY h.from_time;

  END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF;
```

The condition `WHERE  timestamp_col BETWEEN v_start_time AND interval '24 HOUR' + v_start_time` looks a confusing. You named a parameter "_col" but you use it as if it is a column in on of the tables. Is it a column? Then you don't need to declare it. If not I would recommend to use a different name for the parameter (but maybe this is a result of you trying to obfuscate the code).

Comment: resulting error after executing the functionERROR:  column reference "from_time" is ambiguous
LINE 2: ...SELECT v_start_time + (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY from_time)...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  With Hours As (
        SELECT v_start_time + (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY from_time) - 1) *  INTERVAL '1 day' AS from_time,
               v_start_time + (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY from_time)) *  INTERVAL '1 day' AS to_time
        FROM   table_2

Comment: @Parth: Then prefix the column name with the table alias (and you should also avoid using a parameter name that is identical to a column name).

Comment: Yes timestamp_col is the column name.in my case there are two table table_1 with column [timestamp_col,param_value] and table_2 with columns [from_time,to_time].Yes you are write i have corrected and added date_param as parameter and deleted other parameters which were actually column name.

Comment: Return Table(date_param date,from_time time, to_time time, diff integer) i want date_param which is the parameter should also be returened as the result of the function.Can i use the above statement for that

Comment: @Parth: just add a new column definition in the `returns table (...)` part and include the parameter in the `select` statement.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test4(date_param date)
RETURNS TABLE(date_param date,from_time time without time zone, to_time time without time zone, diff integer) AS ....<other statements>..... SELECT date_param,CAST(h.from_time as time), 
             CAST(h.to_time as time),
             MAX(t1.param_value) - MIN(t1.param_value) as diff
      FROM   table_1 t1......ERROR:  parameter name "date_param" used more than once
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "test4" near line 1...Sorry for trouble but i am new in postgres and i really need help for this SP